# Booting a BIOS bootloader from UEFI mode

Tags: multi-boot, grub, uefi, bootloader, mbr

I have a Linux setup that I boot in UEFI mode with GRUB. I want to try out OpenBSD, which unfortunately doesn't support GPT or UEFI yet, so I partitioned a drive with a traditional MBR table and installed OpenBSD to that disk using their install CD.

I then attempt to chainload the OpenBSD bootloader in typical GRUB fashion:

```
menuentry "OpenBSD" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod chain
    set root=(hd1,4)
    chainloader +1
}
```

but I am met with "Invalid EFI File Path".

Is it possible to chainload a BIOS bootloader once you have first booted in EFI mode? I can fall back to selecting the drive to boot from in my motherboard's boot menu, but a GRUB menu entry would obviously be preferable.

Comment: See whether this helps - go into the BIOS and set Secure Boot off and Legacy on.

Comment: Setting legacy boot would mean booting in MBR mode instead of UEFI mode. That means I would have to change the partition table on my main drive _and_ redo my current boot setup for Linux and Windows. You can't just "set legacy boot on".

Comment: @MattKline: There's no "MBR mode"; just "BIOS mode". It's unfortunate that _Windows_ refuses to boot in BIOS mode from a GPT disk, but that doesn't mean BIOS implies MBR nor that UEFI implies GPT. (Linux can boot in any combination.)

Comment: @grawity - thanks for the correction. Sorry for conflating the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, no. While you *can* use MBR-partitioned *disks* within UEFI, you cannot use BIOS (MBR) format bootloaders, as they expect to run in a mostly "fresh" system, not inside the UEFI-prepared environment. So GRUB.efi doesn't even attempt to start one; it expects you to give an .efi path only.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do what you want with GRUB, but you *can* do it in at least two other ways, at least with most UEFI-based computers:

- You can use your firmware's built-in boot manager. Typically, you access this via a function key early in the boot process. It should present options to boot whatever EFI-mode boot programs you've installed (such as GRUB, probably via an option named after your distribution) and some others (such as options for external media, network boots, and BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boots). The details of what appears will vary greatly from one machine to another, though.
- You can use my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You'll need to install this in Linux and then edit the `refind.conf` file: Uncomment the `scanfor` line and ensure that `hdbios` is one of the options. You might also need to uncomment the `uefi_deep_legacy_scan` option, but that depends on your firmware. If this generates too many options, you can trim the list by using the `dont_scan_volumes` option. You can try it without installing it by using the USB flash drive version, but you'll need to edit its `refind.conf` file.

Note that these options both depend on the firmware having a flexible Compatibility Support Module (CSM). Most modern UEFI-based systems have such a CSM, but a few (mostly older) implementations actually built UEFI atop a BIOS rather than providing a UEFI with a CSM. These older systems can't switch so easily.